# same keydown on multiple modal on same page

Tags: jquery

I am usign same keydown for all the modal windows on a page. But when multiple popup open same time. I move key on one modal but it start working on rest of the modal windows as well

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if ($tbody.find('.' + highlightClass).length) {

                if (e.which != 40 && e.which != 38) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (e.which == 40) { //down arrow
                    gotoNext();
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else if (e.which == 38) { //up arrow
                    gotoPrevious();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `event.stopPropagation()` before calling `gotoPrevious()` and `gotoNext()`. I would also try calling `e.preventDefault()` **before** calling `gotoPrevious()` and `gotoNext()`

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/